# Typeorm find with where on other side of relation

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have 3 tables as following:

1. users:

   `id`
2. families:

   `id`
3. families_users:

   `familyId | userId`

I have these relations:

```
// User
@OneToMany(() => FamilyUser, (familyUser) => familyUser.user)
familyUsers: FamilyUser[];

// Family
@OneToMany(() => FamilyUser, (familyUser) => familyUser.family)
familyUsers: FamilyUser[];

// FamilyUser
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.familyUsers, { nullable: false })
user: User;

@ManyToOne(() => Family, (family) => family.familyUsers, { nullable: false })
family: Family;
```

I want to get a particular user's family list. The first option is:

```
await this.familiesUsersRepository.find({
  relations: ['family'],
  where: {
    user: { id: 6 },
  },
});
```

But in this case, I get the list of `FamilyUser`s which each one **contains** a family object. But I want to return the list of families that belongs to the user. I tried this:

```
return await this.familiesRepository.find({
  relations: ['familyUsers', 'familyUsers.user'],
  where: {
    // ???
  },
});
```

But have no idea what I should set in the where clause. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got your question but I think you can return one user's family simply by going from userRepository :

```
let idUser = 6 ;
return await this.userRepository.findOne(idUser,{relations: ['familyUsers']});
```

**UPDATED**

```
 return await  this.familyRepository.createQueryBuilder('family')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('family.familyUsers', 'familyusers') 
   .where("familyusers.user = :idUser", { idUser }) // if familyusers.user doesn't work replace 'user' with the name of colmun in the table 
   .getMany()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But not only it doesn't return family as the main object (the main object is user resource) but also it doesn't return family at all.

Comment: What I got from your comment is you want to return a list of family members as a main object right?

Comment: Thanks. although this has a syntax error, but I got your point. Thanks

Comment: you can update my answer with the exact syntax for other users, good luck